# locate <h1> element selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am not able to locate in firefox 'Sitemap' on, http://pages.ebay.com/sitemap.html

```
   <header>
   <div class="nav">
   <a id="mainContent" tabindex="-1"/>
   <h1>Sitemap</h1>
```

Kindly suggest.

```
 boolean abc =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='mainContent']/../h1")).isDisplayed();
 if (abc==true){
     System.out.println("PASS");
 }
 else
 {
     System.out.println("FALSE");
 }
```

error: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@id='mainContent']/../h1"}
Command duration or timeout: 232 milliseconds

Comment: added code and error message as I got correct Xpath

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all the attribute selection syntax is with `@`:

```
//a[@id='mainContent']
```

If you need an `<h1>` element, you should select

```
//h1
```

If you want to select `<h1>` as a sibling of `//a[id='mainContent']`, then

```
//a[@id='mainContent']/../h1
```

Comment: Xpath is correct (when I check Xpath on Firefox using firepath) but I still get following error in my code.    Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@id='mainContent']/../h1"}
Command duration or timeout: 232 milliseconds

Comment: are you waiting for page to load completely? try this: `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions. presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@id='mainContent']/../h1")));`

Answer (score 1):

Try `By.cssSelector('.nav h1')` (it gets h1 tag inside the class="nav")

Answer (score 1):

use the below:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#mainContent~h1")).isDisplayed();
```

hope this will help you.